# mysql database not rendering german character correctly

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8

Update:
it turns out this is not directly related to the DB server itself, but the clients encoding.  If the client uses encoding utf8, the german character is rendered incorrectly.  But if the client uses  encoding cp850, then the german character is rendered correctly. But I need to use utf8 since there might be other class of characters that the app needs to deal with.  what should I do?

Original:

I have two database servers, viewing from the same mysql cient, server1 is rendering the german characters correctly, server2 is not.  the following are the differences.  But I'm baffled since server2 uses utf8 more.  What could be the cause of this?
server1's encodings:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character\_set\_database";
+------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name          | Value  |
+------------------------+--------+
| character_set_database | latin1 |
+------------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | cp850  |
| character_set_connection | cp850  |
| character_set_database   | latin1 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | cp850  |
| character_set_server     | latin1 |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
```

## server2

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | utf8   |
| character_set_connection | utf8   |
| character_set_database   | utf8   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | utf8   |
| character_set_server     | utf8   |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character\_set\_database";
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| character_set_database | utf8  |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Did you copy the data from Server1 to Server2? If so, how?

Comment: You didn't answer the question in your update

Comment: @Pekka: no I didn't copy the data from server1 to server2.

Comment: This is kinda hard to answer, since it could have many reasons: It could be that the *data* is broken as opposed to the connection. That often happens when copying / importing data with the wrong settings. Not sure what to recommend ..... where does the data on the server come from where it's broken?